# How do I remove the top element from queue in OCaml

Tags: queue, ocaml

Is there any way of deleting the top most element of the queue in Ocaml? Queue module has only take and pop operation which deletes from the front.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the definition of a queue is that you can only access or remove the *least* recently added element.  It sounds like you also want to remove the most recently added element, is that right?  The general structure for this is called a deque, which lets you add and remove at both ends.  You can find one in the [Batteries Included Deque module](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatDeque.html).

There's nothing like this in the OCaml Standard library, but it also wouldn't be *so* hard to code it up yourself.  You partition the elements into two lists, one with most recent first, the other with least recent first.  You aim to keep the two lists roughly balanced in size, and you require that they both be nonempty if the deque has at least two elements.  (Quoting from Okasaki.)